# VS2015 ASHX Files Double Indent

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, httphandler

Don't know if anybody is having this problem but in VS2015 (Community) when editing ASHX files the text editor double indents on enter. Almost like it expects everything to be one indent in already.

The smart formatting fixes this but it's very annoying writing everything that looks out of place then having to format the document every few lines to get it to look right again.

This only happens for ASHX files, every other file (ASPX, CS, etc.) works fine.

I've done some testing:

1. If I install VS2015 Express Web - the indenting on ASHX files works
2. fine If I install VS2015 Express for Desktop AFTER installing Web -
3. ASHX indents broken again If I install VS2015 Desktop then Web - ASHX indents are broken
4. Going back to VS2013 Community there are no
   issues

Looks as though the issue is with other versions of VS2015 that isn't Web.

Can anybody please help?

Does anyone else have this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in VS, Please file a report on connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @Dai thanks - can you confirm you're getting this too? I'm curious who else out there is having this problem.

Comment: This happens to me too.

Comment: I have the same problem. This is certainly a bug as indicated here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5c50c95-4f68-4072-8da0-326b15cefd1c/vs2015-ashx-files-double-indent?forum=visualstudiogeneral